# Highlight a text from HTML document Angularjs on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I am working on a project where I have a checkbox and on click of that checkbox I want to highlight certain text from a document which is HTML document having tags. So, Currently I am able to highlight a single word from that document, but if the word to be highlighted is `"alt"` and `alt` is also  `HTML tag`, So, for this  HTML Document gets messed up. Another thing is If I want to highlight some part of a document which can have more than 3 lines (Not specific) or may be a paragraph.How can I highlight that part ?. To show that document I am using `text-angular directive`. Thanks in advance.

My Highlight Function is -

```
$scope.highlightHTML = function(content, text, className, notByWordBoundry){                    
                    var RegExpEscapeText, str;
                    if (!(content && content.replace)) {
                        return '';
                    }
                    if (!text) {
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
                    }
                    if (!className) {
                        className = 'mark';
                    }
                      RegExpEscapeText = text.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
                      if (!notByWordBoundry) {
                          str = new RegExp('(\\b)' + RegExpEscapeText + '(\\b)','gi');
                      } else {
                          str = new RegExp(RegExpEscapeText,'gi');
                      }
                      return content.replace(str , '<span tabindex="1" class="' + className + '">$&</span>');
                };
```

So here content will always be an html Document.

```
uploadService.getDocumentAsHTML($scope.documentType,uploadService.currentFileName) 
                        .then(function(data) {
                            var parser = new DOMParser(); 
                            var originaldoc = data;
                            var responseData = data;
                            $scope.htmlOriginalDoc = parser.parseFromString(originaldoc, 'text/html');
                            var stringData =  "To serve in an organization that lends me a supportive and co-operative learning environment to diversify skills in Programming, challenge me intellectually and offer me a good potential for future";
                            responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, stringData);
                            $rootScope.data.htmlDocument = responseData;
                            $scope.showloadingdocument = true;

                        }, function(error) {
                            $scope.errorMessage = error.status + " : " + error.statusText;
                            toastr.error($scope.errorMessage, 'Error : ' + error.status);
                            if (error.status === 401) {
                                loginService.authenticationError();
                            }
                        })
                        .finally(function () {
                            $scope.fetchingDocumentAsHTML = false;
                        });                    
                };
```

Comment: could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: Yes sure , I have added the code.